# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

Below is the error I see in the console when I try to login to the website. On further inspection, error is happening at the line: *parent.angular.element..* as shown below. What exactly this error mean?

*Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.mywebsite.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.*

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
<script>
**parent.angular.element(parent.document.getElementById('loginform')).scope().gcdmHandleLoginResponse(window.location.href);**
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't access a parent window when the origin (domain, port, subdomain etc) is not the same as the page in the frame. You can try setting `document.domain` in the frame page to match parent

Comment: This is an example of cross-site scripting (XSS), which is not allowed. Lookup "same-origin policy".

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of XSS - if you're not already familiar with cross-site scripting, you can read up on it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

You will want to ensure both the parent and child frame are on the same domain.